# eclipse - swt - using windowbuilder in xfce env

Tags: eclipse, linux-kernel, swt, archlinux, xfce

I have some problems with eclipse indigo x64 Linux; The problem is using windowbuilder (the SWT); I tried using gwt or swing but they both cause either windowbuilder freeze or even eclipse crash...

The alike issue it seems I found related info in official eclipse indigo offline Help which says :

> **How can I prevent the preview window from flashing under Linux using Metacity**
>
> In order to create the graphics that you see in the design view,
>   WindowBuilder Pro creates an off screen window containing the various
>   widgets and they takes a screen snapshot of them. This works very well
>   under Windows, OSX and some versions of Linux. Recent versions of the
>   Metacity window manager (more recent than 2.1.4), however, have been
>   modified/"fixed" to disallow windows to be opened off screen. This
>   forces the preview window to appear on screen leading to an annoying
>   flashing effect any time you make a change. The solution is to disable
>   the Metacity "fully_onscreen" constraint by patching the Metacity
>   source code and rebuilding and installing the patched version into
>   your system.
>
> Here are the steps to follow:
>
> 1. Download the Metacity source code from ftp://ftp.gnome.org/pub/gnome/sources/metacity/
> 2. Unpack the source code tarball into any temporary directory.
> 3. Chdir into this directory (with the unpacked code).
> 4. Find window.c file and open it with your favourite texteditor.
> 5. Find a line with "window->require_fully_onscreen = TRUE;"
> 6. Replace it with "window->require_fully_onscreen = FALSE;"
> 7. Save the changes and close the editor.
> 8. Open a terminal and chdir into the directory with the source code (nice if you have already done this)
> 9. Run "./configure".
>
>    10. Run "make all".
>    11. Make sure that steps 9 & 10 completed without errors.
>    12. Become root (or execute the next command via "sudo" depending on the Linux you are running)
>    13. Run "make install" (or "sudo make install").
>    14. Save your work and close any application you are working with.
>    15. End your session (or press Ctrl-Alt-Delete to restart the x-server) and log in again.
>    16. You are done!

well seems like I have the snapshot really but, as I can get it, the snapshot doesn't want to dispose or similar so I have either resize the whole eclipse or press F5 to refresh (which works not at once);

I am not sure how to fix the issue in case I have xfce+adwaita installed? I don't have metacity installed; Seems like xfce works with gtk instead of metacity (correct me if I am wrong);

So my question is... how to fix the "window flashing or freezing" if I have :

- xfce4
- adwaita-dark theme
- linux arch x64ce

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try to install install libswt-gtk-3-jni and libswt-gtk-3-java.

Comment: Thank you for your answer; But I couldn't find the package libswt-gtk-3-java in official repository; And why should I install the *jni package as well? You mean eclipse needs some native stuff?